# File validation using Observables RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm trying to solve a classical file validation process using Rxjava. I have a CSV file with normal headers and another list of headers which I need to verify if they fall under those chosen datatypes or if a value is null.

I have a implemented this using normal java but I want to make my validation code more reactive. This is what I have achieved till this point.

```
String filePath = "/home/user/Documents/test.csv";
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
Map<String,String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
headerMap.put("feild11","String");
headerMap.put("feild10","String");
headerMap.put("feild9","Date");
headerMap.put("feild8","NOT-NULL");

// An map observalble which defines my valdiation rules
Observable<Map<String,String>> fieldsToValidae = Observable.just(headerMap);

Observable<String> fileObservalbe = RxFileReader.from(path);
// An observalbe which gives a list of headers
Observable<String> headers = fileObservalbe.first();

// An observalbe which gives me list of feild values
Observable<String> feildValues = fileObservalbe.skip(1);
```

Here I have 3 observables to combine and validate in the first instance(line) the validation fails.

Here is sample data I want to work with :

**Headers:**

> FirstName|LastName|Gender|DOB|feild1|feild2|feild3|feild4|feild5|feild6|feild7|feild8|feild9|feild10|feild11

**Values:**

> Prakash|joshi|M|11/25/2015|a fdf f|adf |saf |asf|dfadf |sadf | |asdf
>   |asdfsdf|asdf|dfsfcded Prakash|joshi|M|10/25/2015|a fdf f|adf |saf
>   |asf|dfadf |sadf | |asdf |asdfsdf|asdf|dfsfcded
>   Prakash|joshi|M|10/25/2015|a fdf f|adf |saf |asf|dfadf |sadf | |asdf
>   |asdfsdf|asdf|dfsfcded

I am pretty much stuck at this point can anyone help or point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combineLatest operator, pass inside header and fields (as I understood you will have one header emitted and a lots of fields), and in Function pass logic for data validation

```
Observable<Result> validationResultObservable = Observable.combineLatest(headers, feildValues, new Func2<String, String, Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result call(String header, String field) {
                // header always same
                // field always new
                // validate, create same kind of Result object or just a boolean
                Log.i("TEST_IT", "validationResultObservable emitted: " + header + " - " + field);
                return new Result(header, field);
            }
        });
```